# What kind of two-pin connector is just a little smaller than jack 3.5?

Tags: amplifier, audio, connector, cases

I found an old DIY amplifier that I would like to use, but I ran into a problem: I don't know what kind of connector it has.
I know for sure that this device is an amplifier, since I once used it and I even vaguely remember the appearance of the connector (it looked like a jack), but about 10 years have passed, and I can’t remember more.

I remembered that the connectors for this amplifier were short (like jack 2.5) and only with 2 pins (TS). Unfortunately, I don’t have 2.5 connectors on my hands, but it looks like they need more than 2.5 sizes. The 3.5 connector is only slightly larger than the connector on amplifer.

I was surprised by the connectors on the front panel - they are wider than the 3.5 jack (it dangles there), besides, they are too shallow for 3.5 and do not fix the plug. I don't need them, but it would be interesting to find out about them too.

**Does anyone have any suggestions what kind of connectors there might be?**
[image: photos of incomprehensible connectors]
[image: photos of incomprehensible connectors]
[image: photos of incomprehensible connectors]

[image: photos of incomprehensible connectors]

Comment: It looks like a 2.5 mm jack. These were popular on older earpieces. Check with a 2.5 mm drill bit.

Comment: @Transistor Unfortunately no. I had to try many connectors before I found the right one. The clue I found - Soviet radio components (capacitors, resistors) - helped a lot. I started looking for Soviet connectors and ... I found it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It took a lot of time and attempts to find the right fork. In the end, I succeeded. The photo, as it turned out, shows the "**ГК2**" connector. [image: ГК2]

Accordingly, the "**Ш2П**" plug is suitable for this connector.

[image]

All these are old Soviet (from the USSR) connectors.

Comment: ГК2 (GK-2) is supposed to be 2mm.. that doesn't quite fit with your "slightly less than 3.5mm".. is it actually 2mm?

Comment: @Spehro Pefhany The fact is that I do not have a caliper. Empirically, I realized that *3.5 jack* is too big and is not included. *Jack 2.5* comes in "ok" but too short. Normally a nail came in, which was *larger* than jack 2.5.

Comment: I began to search on various sites with used Soviet electronics, on one of which I found **ГК2** connectors for sale. In the photo there were many connectors and with different sides. I checked with the existing ones - they matched exactly. Thus, I recognized the connector, and then ordered a plug. The plug fits. Fixes normally. True, I have not connected the speaker yet - I did not have time and speaker for test. However, I'm sure it will work if the amplifier is alive.